# How to set query criteria to select all when combobox is left empty

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been trying to use `combobox's` value as a criteria for a selection query. I want it to select all options when combobox is left empty.

I have tried to use `isNull` and `isEmpty` functions with `IIF` but the result is always empty rows.

```sql
IIf(IsNull([Forms]![ReportOpener]![EnteredYear])=True;[Forms]![ReportOpener]![EnteredYear] Like "*")
```

```sql
IIf(IsEmpty([Forms]![ReportOpener]![EnteredYear])=True;[Forms]![ReportOpener]![EnteredYear] Like "*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the old trick - to filter on the field itself (which always will match):

```
Nz([Forms]![ReportOpener]![EnteredYear];[YourFieldToFilter])
```

Comment: I don't want to filter it. If a certain value is chosen from combobox in a form, I want to use as a criteria for selection query. If it is left empty, I want the query to show all entries.

Comment: Yes, that what it does.

Answer (score 0):

A more readable approach similar to your attempts might be:

```
select * from YourTable
where 
    [Forms]![ReportOpener]![EnteredYear] is null or 
    YourTable.YourField = [Forms]![ReportOpener]![EnteredYear]
```

Changing `YourTable` & `YourField` to suit.